# Centering a non-fixed width font in a field using Intermec Printing Language version 12

Tags: alignment, ipl, intermec

We are trying to create printer codes to send a maximum 18 character text field to a label printer using IPL version 12. This field will not always hit the max and we need it centered. Is there a way to center a font that is not fixed width in a text field using this printer language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually a firmware issue. New firmware should fix the issue.

Comment: Indeed it was a firmware issue and it was fixed. This was for an Intermec PB-32 printer btw.